# What does the embedding elements stand for in huggingFace bert model?

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, word-embedding

Prior to passing my tokens through encoder in BERT model, I would like to perform some processing on their embeddings. I extracted the embedding weight using:

```
from transformers import TFBertModel

# Load a pre-trained BERT model
model = TFBertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

# Get the embedding layer of the model
embedding_layer = model.get_layer('bert').get_input_embeddings()

# Extract the embedding weights
embedding_weights = embedding_layer.get_weights()
```

I found it contains 5 elements as shown in Figure.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSCfy.png)

In my understanding, the first three elements are the word embedding weights, token type embedding weights, and positional embedding weights. My question is what does the last two elements stand for?

I dive deep into the source code of bert model. But I cannot figure out the meaning of the last two elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bert model, there is a post-processing of the embedding tensor that uses layer normalization followed by dropout ,
https://github.com/google-research/bert/blob/eedf5716ce1268e56f0a50264a88cafad334ac61/modeling.py#L362

I think that those two arrays are the gamma and beta of the normalization layer, https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LayerNormalization
They are learned parameters, and will span the axes of inputs specified in param "axis" which defaults to -1 (corresponding to 768 in embedding tensor).